# How to I retrieve the value of "Answer" of the largest "TimeStamp" from my Real-Time Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to retrieve the value of "Answer" of the largest "TimeStamp".

I've tried using the codes provided by Google in their docs about Firebase.

This is the code i tried:

```
var ref = db.ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("weight").limitToLast(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

However it does not work.

This is my version of when using the codes from Google:

```
function checkMathAnswer(agent){

    var ref = admin.database().ref('MathAnswer');
  ref.orderByChild("TimeStamp").limitToLast(1).once('value').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
    });

  }
```

For example, currently in my DB, there are 2 data. I'm trying to retrieve 
"Answer: 161" since the "TimeStamp" is larger than the other one.

So in the future, whenever I'm trying to run this function, its suppose to retrieve the Answer with the Largest TimeStamp.

[image: This is my Database][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY1D5.png)